# how to fix json_str = combiner.to_json(orient='records') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

```
def get_data_2nd_sheet(self):
          holiday_d = holiday_data.HolidayData(conn=self.conn)
          combiner = sow_report_by_sow_level_no_combiner.MonthlyReportBySowLevel(conn=self.conn).generate_report()
          print(type(combiner),"hiiii")
           # Convert Timestamp objects to strings
          json_str = combiner.to_json(orient='records')
          return json_str
```

I tried different methods also used `json.dump` but, not getting the exact result.

Answer (score 1):

From you code it looks that your `combiner` is `None`.

Can you please print and check whether `combiner` has any value?

Print this thing and see what you get:

```
print(sow_report_by_sow_level_no_combiner.MonthlyReportBySowLevel(conn=self.conn).generate_report())
```

If you are getting `None` that means this is the problem and fix it.

If you do this:

```
None.to_json()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```